# Titles should not be able to literally contain "[on hold]"

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, on-hold

A user just posted this question:

[Ubuntu booting stuck at checking battery status after upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10 [on hold]](https://superuser.com/questions/623057/ubuntu-booting-stuck-at-checking-battery-status-after-upgrade-from-10-04-to-11-1)

The title literally contains `[on hold]`. Before the closing process was renamed, it was not possible to have a title contain `[closed]`, so having `[on hold]` should not be possible either.

(Obviously it's a [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791205/ubuntu-booting-stuck-at-checking-battery-status-after-upgrade-from-10-04-to-11-1), where the user was too lazy to check what they copy-pasted.)

Comment: I wanna see "Titles can literally contain [oh hold]? [on hold]" ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - easy one. Just close this one ;)

Comment: @Oded or, edit the title!

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, more a feature request but yeah, agree it should be done. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Of course it's a bug. Previously, you couldn't have `[closed]` in the title, so why should you be able to write `[on hold]`?

Comment: I think you still can't have [closed] in title. Bug is when something breaks or causing undesired results. Anyway it's really not a big deal. :)

Comment: Bugs get squashed; feature requests get squashed sometimes, too. Doesn't mean the same thing. And none of this nonsense comment is related to anything here in the slightest!

Comment: Now investigating if titles can metaphorically contain [on hold]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in revision 2013.7.23.1259 (meta) / 2013.7.23.883 (sites).

Comment: For cheap laughs, now try editing this question...